# ReactJS: Uncaught in promise when calling fetch()

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a problem with the data that I am fetching. I'm getting a uncaught in promise with my fetch call. That goes to say I also don't know if my code is even possible code or good code.

I have a filterbar where the user selects two dates, that means I put those input fields in a form, again not sure if I should do that, but that way I now have a onSubmit on my form. This onSubmit takes my function handleSubmit which calls my fetch.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SplitButton, Dropdown, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CarCard from '../components/results/CarCard'

//YYYY-MM-DD

class SearchBar extends Component {
    state = {
        fromDate: '',
        toDate: '',
        data: [],
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.getData()
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    getData = () => {
        const { toDate, fromDate } = this.state
        var url = 'https://www.fenonline.dk/SYS_Backend/api/car/'
        url += fromDate + "/"
        url += toDate
        const data_promise = fetch(url).then(handleHttpErrors)
        data_promise.then(data => this.setState({ data }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Container style={styles.container} fluid={true} >
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <h5 style={{ color: 'white', }}>Search for your rental here:</h5>
                        <input type="date" label="test" name='fromDate' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <input type="date" placeholder={this.state.toDate} name='toDate' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <input type='submit' value='search' />
                    </form>
                </Container>
                <Container>
                    {carCardItems(this.state.data) || 'Please wait...'}
                </Container>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}


export default SearchBar;

const carCardItems = data => {
    const items = data.map(c =>
        <CarCard key={c.regno} {...c} />
    );
    return items;
};

function handleHttpErrors(res) {
    if (!res.ok) {
        return Promise.reject({ status: res.status, fullError: res.json() })
    }
    return res.json();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could rewrite `getData()` using `async/await` to better capture all possible code paths for uncaught errors/promises:

```
/* Define async function */
getData = async () => {

    /* This try block will encapsulate the fetch logic, and capture all errors
       that can be thrown */
    try {

        const { toDate, fromDate } = this.state
        var url = 'https://www.fenonline.dk/SYS_Backend/api/car/'
        url += fromDate + "/"
        url += toDate

        /* Use await instead of promise.then */
        const response = await fetch(url)

        /* The json() function is async, so use await */
        const json = await response.json()

        /* If response failed, return error data in same format as in your 
           Promise.reject() */
        if(!response.ok) {
            throw { status: response.status, fullError: json } 
        }

        /* Update data with json */
        this.setState({ data : json })
    }
    catch(error) {

        /* Log error to console */
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Also note that `response.json()` [is an asynchronous method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), which means you'll need to call it via `await` as shown above (or as a promise;  `res.json().then(...)`). This means that doing:

```
return Promise.reject({ status: res.status, fullError: res.json() })
```

as shown in your code will mean the value of `fullError` is a `Promise` object, rather than the expected JSON data

Answer (score 0):

**Uncaught in promise** means , an exception pops up somewhere, which is not handled (no catch block).

in this case inside getData, fetch needs a catch block. see below

```
const data_promise = fetch(url).then(handleHttpErrors).catch(error => {console.error(error);})
```